# String format not correct when sent over to email.

Tags: android, email, string-formatting

When I print out on my console, my String format aligns fine. But when I send this String over to an email, the alignment always shifts. Do I need to take note of anything extra when sending it as an email?

Printing Straight to console:

```
static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String[] args){
    names.add("Chair");
    names.add("Desk");
    names.add("Photo Frame");
    names.add("Stool");

    numbers.add(452);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(15);
    numbers.add(1232);

    String order = String.format("%-30s %s", "Name", "Quantity\n\n");
    for(int x=0; x<names.size(); x++){
        order+= String.format("%-30s %s", names.get(x), numbers.get(x) + "\n");
    }
    String finalString = "New orders made. Please refer to list below.\n\n" + order;
    System.out.println(finalString);
}
```

The output as follows which is correct:

```
New orders made. Please refer to list below.

Name                    Quantity

Chair                   452 
Desk                    5 
Photo Frame             15 
Stool                   1232
```

Sending the String to an email. The String has same content.

```
private void sendEmail(){

        String order = String.format("%-30s %s", "Name", "Quantity\n\n");
        for(int x=0; x < names.size(); x++){
            order+= String.format("%-30s %s", names.get(x), numbers.get(x)) + "\n";
        }

        try {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"adasda@adad.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "New Orders");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "New orders made. Please refer to list below.\n\n" + order);
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(emailIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You do not have an email client", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output over at email which is not aligned:

```
New orders made. Please refer to list below.

Name                    Quantity

Chair                  452 
Desk                   5 
Photo Frame                15 
Stool                  1232
```

Answer (score 0):

change `%-30s %s` to `%-40s %s` or slightly higher and you should be fine.

Comment: Tried with %-40s %s and %-50s %s. Still misaligned.

Comment: How about using tabs \t

Comment: yes i was about to suggest that but then the number of tabs will be different for the line with `Photo Frame`. probably one less. If he loops with the same number of tabs it will end up rendering the same output.